# Retry failed mocha api tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, mocha.js

I'm having a lot of random auto-tests false failures which works fine when re-running it again. Is there any way to re-run the failed api mocha tests? I've already tried using `this.retries(x)` but it doesn't seem to be re-running it for me. Also would it show on the report if we are re-running the tests?

I'm using the similar kind of code in my tests:

```
describe('Get file jobs', function() {
this.retries(3);

describe('More describe blocks', function() {
    before('do something', function(done) {
        // do something
        done();
    })

    it('should GET /api/file/id', function(done) {
        // do something 
        // should run three times if it fails
        done();
    })
  })

})
```

**Mocha version:** 2.4.5

Comment: I would say fix the test cases. A test is useless if it randomly fails.

Comment: @Josnidhin Yes,I am working on that but I was wondering if there was any way to re-run those tests to see if it passes again or not?

Comment: Please add some sample code of how you are using `this.retries` and the version of mocha being used.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax and mocha version looks fine. I think its re-running the test case but is failing the re-runs also. Do something like the following to test the number of times it runs.

```
var counter = 0;

describe('Get file jobs', function() {
  this.retries(3);
  describe('More describe blocks', function() {
    before('do something', function(done) {
      // do something
      done();
    })

    it('should GET /api/file/id', function(done) {
      counter++;
      console.log(counter);
      // do something 
      // should run three times if it fails
      done();
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: you could use ```this.test._currentRetry``` instead of your own counter

Comment: Wow @Keegan'shairstyle82 that is super cool, I couldn't find `this.test._currentRetry` in the docs, can you please share a link to this?

Comment: @Noitidart I'm afraid I have no documentation to reference, I think I must of found it using a debugger.

Comment: Thanks very much @Keegan'shairstyle82!